# D3D11Texture2D to another texture with different context and device

Tags: c++, directx-11, dxgi

I am trying to copy a texture surface to a texture from a different context to create a sharedBitmap, but in result a black picture. What's wrong?

```
hr = device->CreateTexture2D(&texDesc, 0, &tmpTexture);

IDXGIResource1* pOtherResource(NULL);
hr = secondTexture->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIResource), (void**)&pOtherResource);
HANDLE sharedHandle;
hr = pOtherResource->GetSharedHandle(&sharedHandle);

hr = device->OpenSharedResource(sharedHandle, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)&tmpTexture);

m_DeviceContext->CopyResource(tmpTexture, secondTexture);
```

Comment: I want copy from secondTexture to tmpTexture. tmp texture created by device, second by m_DeviceContext. How to do it?

Comment: You don't need to call  hr = device->CreateTexture2D(&texDesc, 0, &tmpTexture); if you plan to use OpenSharedResource to initialize tmpTexture from a shared handle.

Comment: Also check all the hr results to see if any errors occur. There are some limitations as well, such as MSAA textures can not be shared. Check the requirements at the end 
here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11device-opensharedresource

Answer (score 1):

Texture sharing is possible but there are important limitations.

First of all, you need to enable debug layer and check for debug output the debug SDK layer possibly emits.

Second, it does not follow from your question that the two devices in question belong to the same DXGI adapter, and it is important.

Third, there might be synchronization involved, neglecting which would result in blackness: [Surface Sharing Between Windows Graphics APIs -- DXGI 1.1 Synchronized Shared Surfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3darticles/surface-sharing-between-windows-graphics-apis#dxgi-11-synchronized-shared-surfaces).